# How to trim hex and convert it to string

Tags: javascript, string, hex, trim

Let's say I have a line of hex

```
4f6c69766572204d6973202020202020
```

When I use my Javascript function to convert it into string and return this:

`Oliver Mis`<-- there are spaces at the end, because 202020202020 is spaces.

How can I remove the extra spaces at the end of the string. Because space between `Oliver' 'Mis`, I don't want to remove it. I'm trying to do something like if it meets 2 spaces, then only take up to `4f6c69766572204d6973` which is Oliver Mis.

This is my convert hex into string function:

```
function hextostring(hexx) {
  var hex = hexx.toString();//force conversion
  var str = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
    str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
  return str;
}
```

Comment: `trim` before converting to Hex.

Comment: `return str.trim();`

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.Trim()`:

```
function hextostring(hexx) {
    var hex = hexx.toString();
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
        str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    return str.Trim();
}
```

> Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the current String object.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx)